# Adding a letter to the x-axis ticks of pgfplots graph of function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs, axis

I'm new to stack exchange, so please let me know if there is anything I should do to make my question more clear.

I'm new to LaTeX, and I am trying to make a graph of the equation [image] from special relativity.  I want my y-axis to be gamma and my x-axis to be the velocity, v.

I have my graph (picture below), but I just want to do one more thing.  When I graphed the function, I used 1/(1-x^2) as my function (basically, x acts as v/c) so the max value would be 1, which would represent 1c (the speed of light).  How do I add $c$ to each of the numbers on the x-axis? For example, how do I turn 0.2 into 0.2c? I have seen other questions like this, but they are graphing data, not functions, so the code doesn't work for my graph.  If possible, I'd like to not have to enter the equation as a data set; I want to keep it as a function.  Thank you in advance!

Also, here is my current code for the graph (please let me know if something can be improved):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[scaled y ticks=false, xlabel=$v$, ylabel=$\gamma$, ymax=5]
        \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=1000] {1/sqrt(1-x^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My current graph:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have you tried `xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}c$}`? Cf. the example in section 4.15 of the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I had not tried that, but it works! Thank you so much for your help.  Would you mind giving a short explanation of how that works?

Comment: I glad it worked.  `\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}` prints the value at the tick and all I have done is add the variable `c`.  But this is a duplicate of another question on the site.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Actually, I already saw that one, but it didn't work. (I'm guessing it was because it wasn't surrounded by $)

Comment: The math mode switching ($...$ or \(...\)) are only necessary for the "styling" of the output.  The code in that answer works as posted, but the result would be better in math mode, as in the comment to the answer.